# GWT CellTable getVisibleRange() is not what i except

Tags: gwt, pagination, gwt-celltable

GWT2.4, CellTable with SimplePager, every page show 5 items(rows), suppose i have 8 items totally, at the first page i can see [1-5], when i press next, it will show [4-8] ( getVisibleRange() is [4-8]), i want it to show [6-8], Is there any way i can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
setRangeLimited(false)
```

with SimplePager

Or you can also override

```
@Override
public void setPageStart(int index) {
  if (getDisplay() != null) {
    Range range = getDisplay().getVisibleRange();
    int pageSize = range.getLength();

    // Removed the min to show fixed ranges
    //if (isRangeLimited && display.isRowCountExact()) {
    //  index = Math.min(index, display.getRowCount() - pageSize);
    //}

    index = Math.max(0, index);
    if (index != range.getStart()) {
      getDisplay().setVisibleRange(index, pageSize);
    }
  }
```